# My emails are seen as spam by Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, postfix, spam-prevention, email-server

I have a email server with postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, etc.
[www.mail-tester.com](http://www.mail-tester.com) gives me 10/10.
[www.spamscore.net](http://www.spamscore.net) complains about the spf (SPF record SOFTFAIL) and reverse DNS: I have neither asked my ISP to change the PTR record nor do I have a static ip address.

What can I do?

These are the headers according to Gmail and everything seems ok to me, except the PTR record...:

```
Delivered-To: gmail_user@gmail.com
Received: by xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx:xx:xx:xxxx:xxxx with SMTP id c19csp344692rch;
        Tue, 16 May 2023 06:08:11 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ACHHUZ4vxiX67a0XTZCDu/km6NL865PkDFPhLSzzQgCCAmjNdfe1JG/e92WiW/ba6TjefmeV+NoT
X-Received: by xxxx:xxx:xxxx:x:xx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx with SMTP id b7-20020aa7c907000000b0050dd98add15mr2299049edt.38.1684242491465;
        Tue, 16 May 2023 06:08:11 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1684242491; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=qumQE9U/4c0UtI82AK73ykWU+wddfWysdzHT0duMwijPySrmetLYLAdPViPtlUB0ph
         vIMb27P2vjR8WEa6cie+zQZ8Hw9yPt7AheOYgyRQ2sLWtO3SYTt86ExtrJ5PBLq3nPJM
         GvJHw70/eS28S5H5WX/StANGh2fC/hf36zpdovnqnjqaRbi4PZESNRfiz3JVDPbQJrke
         aAsEoMKwzX3KyiTvwgr25NgSq/j5NKhzf4qcAOYRAA16WlSJo212PIzZ+6YrW7J9rDYw
         FfXK8EPs2RkBo8xaEX0LzstSJo+A9sBbZiZu8IOIdeDk32o6oP3sXQ0Inw8EXy4O/SKQ
         JYaQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-transfer-encoding:list-unsubscribe:list-unsubscribe
         :mime-version:message-id:user-agent:subject:to:from:date
         :dkim-signature:dkim-signature;
        bh=4RTOY/L7fEh3E7bKPR/wW8ZxxPpUcJcPGgjnnt1mxQg=;
        b=jA6IpOhiyrFfWbHmVBonOnDnKdSpHy+vvqLtARNNiRi+7mX0D0Dwwqif3EGtpY8rqy
         CbfuBzjtT/YXssP6nvDgkys3xtVPttH6VqoWdIAwfIgiV1wxzKBUQry+YdlzETcRScsy
         MesXBPRmIxUlVDp+WSvVDDyVIQU66MdHPX27druWNl6uOmPYOCi6zMFlGzpQLW3pcYEP
         pT+fcTmkzpBemWgLmrV7h5C0Uo67HjXuVUux/OmhedzpiSfTZ9/wQYKUHVS+jJR3cTPz
         RgiBWj54F/DSieFn41raTiiLF9AxQBtDgy4avkspEiv24sBceaiajczBlns1JCeSypm3
         xefA==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@my-domain.com header.s=default header.b=erU5MmE3;
       dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify) header.i=@my-domain.com header.s=default header.b=h2fQ8KlA;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@my-domain.com designates xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@my-domain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=my-domain.com
Return-Path: <user@my-domain.com>
Received: from mail.my-domain.com (p200300e997106c85ba27ebfffebb66f4.dip0.t-ipconnect.de. [xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id p16-20020a056402045000b0050bc45d5813si16499100edw.237.2023.05.16.06.08.11
        for <gmail_user@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Tue, 16 May 2023 06:08:11 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of user@my-domain.com designates xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx as permitted sender) client-ip=xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@my-domain.com header.s=default header.b=erU5MmE3;
       dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify) header.i=@my-domain.com header.s=default header.b=h2fQ8KlA;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of user@my-domain.com designates xxxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=user@my-domain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=my-domain.com
Received: by mail.my-domain.com (Postfix, from userid 109) id 9913F3CA6; Tue, 16 May 2023 13:08:07 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=my-domain.com; s=default; t=1684242487; bh=4RTOY/L7fEh3E7bKPR/wW8ZxxPpUcJcPGgjnnt1mxQg=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:List-Unsubscribe:From; b=erU5MmE3HyDCKPJ8ezhzJ1H6p+B1iw0U0AU13RU7fDMeaXrZdnMKm7cVyvaRYbJ6X
     NpU1/qmQccj2haf6qpB+Db1Y2tTC2fAo7OYeD+mBmSDuO6/iMqNaUgwf0ty1tQvKAo
     hv6sP6AXtf0vWTnVuVulpq1diCdUSrCOtQhuzAVmW7XvARyghZEDwDhP1xSpi6ZZzq
     cgxSH1hWgTvND6bSDSMYjSuhKA1OJjWBv8STMcFT0Iu3fxMI6l3IhtmnqUnUhn63aD
     RZvRPGjhptkcQIYR8iA5DudUvHlwsuGuy5lFZRLDiwPD2SZrsjVqr1Fwzy8HnJ2Ge3
     gx6+juU/9cmWQ==
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.6 (2021-04-09) on my-computer.Speedport_W_724V_Typ_A_05011603_06_003
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.1 required=5.0 tests=ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED, DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,T_SCC_BODY_TEXT_LINE, URIBL_BLOCKED autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no version=3.4.6
Received: from [127.0.0.1] (dynamic-046-114-006-210.46.114.pool.telefonica.de [46.114.6.210]) (using TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits)
     key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256) (No client certificate requested) by mail.my-domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 166203C95 for <gmail_user@gmail.com>; Tue, 16 May 2023 13:07:54 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=my-domain.com; s=default; t=1684242475; bh=nHNlsXdplV+gXG0VuUvNHDw/RyaACF99+XI8vu7+m3A=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:List-Unsubscribe:From; b=h2fQ8KlAb0gcSJ9g9Gn2hrkQ81s81+EoKh5KeyhMRmiKhMQkPtdGUuJTparRjOi6l
     mng0pXysmFBUcHshZUT/XpnFwWqiQNxt8DuiY2YTkw8DXHx+UdLBprBJ2HskOMO7Lg
     PklQBaoPsrEJXTs53oSpHqgPMXRRNwcgfYa66AWcIi63Pn8sxn5TgOwhk3DT+451HH
     LuzYILfq1xfo4RROKPaCP9zNKwRY72OrGdrlD6skb4dBdXYKF+vSSJLOqxk5vBcFMx
     tt5OPMAUhSmoUbWXj+UNS3wD58iclWM+CYoYLVzC6TI+lGMliomHEURvjybqufacn7
     JDirRAIDst+YQ==
Date: Tue, 16 May 2023 15:07:47 +0200
From: John <user@my-domain.com>
To: gmail_user@gmail.com
Subject: Subject here
User-Agent: K-9 Mail for Android
Message-ID: <0706826F-14A2-4477-B066-985D75C71882@my-domain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=----8DTU44YRN9DS835N8LAPEHSE9DSIVO
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

------8DTU44YRN9DS835N8LAPEHSE9DSIVO
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Dear John,

Body here.

Best regards,
John
------8DTU44YRN9DS835N8LAPEHSE9DSIVO
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@my-domain.com?subject=unsubscribe>"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div dir=3D"auto">Dear John,<br><br>Body=
here.<br><br>Best regards,<br>John</div></body></ht=
ml>
------8DTU44YRN9DS835N8LAPEHSE9DSIVO--
```

Comment: Did the **original** message, as submitted by K-9 Mail, have all those List-Unsubscribe headers? (Is the "K-9 Mail" header actually true?)

Comment: @user1686: The List-Unsubscribe headers come from postfix. Also true

Answer (score 1):

> I have neither asked my ISP to change the PTR record nor

Gmail requires all IPv6 senders to have a PTR record. Many mail domains also expect the same for IPv4 senders.

There are problems with your DKIM setup – your message is being signed twice, and the way it's set up, your own mailing-list system has no choice but to immediately invalidate it.

Specifically, the first signature (at the bottom) is signing headers that it *should not be signing,* namely the `list-unsubscribe` header (or lack thereof). So if the DKIM signature asserts that there is *no* such header, but then your mailing-list software immediately adds one, this very likely results in a DKIM validation failure.

It doesn't stop there – if your example is to be believed, the system also adds the List-Unsubscribe header to *each MIME part* (even though this header has no business being there – it only makes sense as a message-level header). Not only is this useless, but if it is done after signing it will invalidate the existing signatures, causing "body hash did not verify" on the receiver's side.

You should 1) stop the system from adding the second signature (the first is enough), 2) stop including "List-Unsubscribe" among the signed headers, 3) stop adding these headers to the individual MIME parts.